# como llamar una funcion de un archivo js externo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He creado una función js y la he guardado en um arquivo externo, como hago para llamar esta funcion en una pagina html?

ejemplo:

```
    $(function () {
     $('#Modal1').modal('show');
    });
```

Cuando el script esta en la misma pagina funciona sim problemas pero cuando lo pongo en um archivo externo no ejecuta la funcion. Alguen tiene idea de lo que puede ser?

Comment: Coloca el script src hasta abajo del body en el archivo html, ya que como lo estan colo cando en el head primero se va al js y no identifica que esta ese id en el html. Saludos

Comment: "ya que como lo estás colocando"?? Dónde ves eso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función que nos muestras se trata de una función anónima que se ejecuta cuando carga el **DOM** de la página y que va a buscar una *modal* que tenga como **ID** *Modal1* y la va a mostrar.

Si quieres que se ejecute lo único que tendrías que hacer es cargar tu archivo externo en dicha página y que exista en ella una modal con la pertinente **ID**:

```
<script src="ruta.mijs.js"></script>
```

Si por otro lado quisieras llamarla en otro momento que no sea al cargar el **DOM** tal y como la tienes no podrías, por tratarse de una función anónima.

En este caso, encapsularla dentro de una función con nombre te podría servir:

```
function mostrar_modal() {
  $('#Modal1').modal('show');
});

mostrar_modal(); //Busca la modal `#Modal1` y la muestra en caso de existir.
```

Comment: Lo he intentado pero no funciona, sera que esto:
mostrar_modal(); //Busca la modal `#Modal1` y la muestra en caso de existir. Lo tengo que colocar dentro de la div donde esta el modal?

Comment: Lo he conseguido colocando en la div de esta forma :  onclick="mostrar_modal();"

Comment: Por eso te explicaba que si querías llamarla en otro momento podías encapsularla en una función con nombre, luego ya la llamas donde necesites, en un `onclick` en un `onchange`, al terminar otra función o donde precises ^^